# perl/mason: assigning value to a global variable in handler.pl

Tags: perl, mason

Is it possible to assign value to a global variable in `handler.pl`?

I need to assign a value to a global variable in `handler.pl`, and get the value from a Mason component.

I tried this way:

**httpd.conf**

```
...
PerlRequire handler.pl
...
```

**handler.pl**

```
...
our $x = 'test';
...
```

**something.mas**

```
...
<h1><% $x %></h1>
...
```

but it is not working, it doesn't return `<h1>test</h1>` but just `<h1></h1>` as `$x` is undefined. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you'll have to set

```
PerlSetVar MasonAllowGlobals $x
```

in httpd.conf, or in handler.pl include

```
allow_globals => [ '$x' ]
```

in your apache handler definition, or declare it in the HTML::Mason::Commands package that the components run in:

```
package HTML::Mason::Commands;
use vars '$x';
```

This last option is also how you can make other Perl modules available in all components:

```
package HTML::Mason::Commands;
use Data::Dumper;
use URI;
...
```

Refer to http://www.masonhq.com/?FAQ:Components#h-can_i_use_globals_in_components_